# Parallel To Serial HDL

Tags: counter, verilog, hdl

I am making a parallel to serial converter using ring counter in verilog. The ring counter is working fine but the Parallel to serial converter is not working properly and I am getting x undefined result. I am providing the code kindly help me finding the problem.

***TOP***

```
module PtoSTOP;

  reg clk,rst;

  wire [3:0] myout;
  wire       out;

  Ring a(clk,rst,myout);

  parToser x(myout,clk,rst,out);

  initial begin 
    clk=1;
    rst=1;

    #1 rst=0; 
 end

 always
   #2 clk=~clk;

 endmodule
```

***Parallel TO Serial Converter***

```
module parToser(myout,clk,rst,out);

input clk,rst;
input [3:0] myout;
output reg  out;

reg [2:0]i;

always @(posedge clk or posedge rst) begin
  if(rst) begin
    out <= 0;
    i   <= 0;
 end
 else begin
   out <= myout[i];
   i   <= i+1;
  end
end

endmodule
```

***RingCounter***

```
module Ring(clk,rst,myout);

input clk,rst;
output reg [3:0]myout;

always @(posedge clk or posedge rst) begin
  if(rst)
    myout<=1;
  else
    myout<=myout<<1;
end

 endmodule
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main issue you are seeing is part of parToser.

You have `reg [2:0]i;` which you increment and use to address `input [3:0] myout;` but i can hold values 0 to 7, half of which is outside the address range of [3:0] myout. You should be seeing a simulation error about out of range addressing.

Also you have included a few flip-flops with a reset condition but not added the reset to the sensitivity list in 'parToser' & 'Ring':

```
always @(posedge clk)
```

Should be:

```
always @(posedge clk or posedge rst)
```

With out this trigger your out, i and myout variables will be x, as they have not been set to a known condition.

NB: parToser `i    = i+1;` should be `i    <= i+1;`

Comment: I am still getting the same output

Comment: Questions are allowed to be a work in progress, as people provided answers they expect the questions to be updated to remove unrelated errors. If questions are not updated to remove the more visible but unrelated errors you will likely get a lot of answers about the easier to spot issues. Any way did spot a small issue with your addressing of the result.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I make non resetting Mealy State transition graph for detecting an input. Lets say `0010`

Comment: Thank you for updating the question. I do not understand the terminology you have used please do ask a new question though, am sure others will be able to help.

Comment: people don't answer such questions here. I have tried to search in on google but couldn't find an answer. Have you any idea how to draw non resetting(the one which doesn't go to initial state when the input is out of sequence but moves to previous states) mealy State transition graph.

Comment: There are a few who watch the verilog tag, if it has anything todo with implementation then they may be able to help. I have never seen the terms non-resetting used in reference to FSMs before. I do not understand your description of out of sequence inputs. Each state will react to inputs and make different transitions, there is no input sequence implied, other that maybe waiting for a certain input before moving on to the next state.

Comment: @UmerFarooq I agree with Morgan, your question is not at all clear. I don't understand your first two responses, either...are you saying you left the code the same and get the same output? That doesn't make sense. Please reduce the problem to a single failing module and show a simulation for that module alone.